# Module not found error while trying to add custom headers using serve.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, header, serve

React Static files Adding headers using serve.js

We have a React based SPA which is served using `CMD ["serve", "-s", "./dist", "-p", "8080"]` in Docker file.

Then there is a requirement to add CSP headers. We tried configuring an `nginx` server and application works fine, but the cypress automation tests were failing randomly. Tried lot of options and no difference.

A suggestion found was to override `serve` by configuring a `serve.js` which contains this

```
const handler = require('serve-handler');
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  // You pass two more arguments for config and middleware
  // More details here: https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler#options
  return handler(request, response);  //{headers }as third param 
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Running at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler#headers-array

Folder strucure
packages
-app-fe-webapp
-src
-serve.js
-Docker

Error when tried with `CMD ["node","serve.js"]` in docker file.

**Error 1**

```
app-fe-webapp-latest | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
app-fe-webapp-latest |   throw err;
app-fe-webapp-latest |   ^
app-fe-webapp-latest | 
app-fe-webapp-latest | Error: Cannot find module 'serve-handler'
app-fe-webapp-latest | Require stack:
app-fe-webapp-latest | - /packages/app-fe-webapp/serve.js
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Object.<anonymous> (/packages/app-fe-webapp/serve.js:1:17)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
app-fe-webapp-latest |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
app-fe-webapp-latest |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
app-fe-webapp-latest |   requireStack: [ '/packages/app-fe-webapp/serve.js' ]
app-fe-webapp-latest | }
app-fe-webapp-latest exited with code 1
```

**Error 2**

Docker file contains

```
RUN yarn global add serve
RUN yarn add serve-handler
```

Error

```
Step 12/16 : RUN yarn add serve-handler
 ---> Running in 088b0937df97
yarn add v1.22.4
error Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the workspace itself, which might not be what you want - if you really meant it, make it explicit by running this command again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check).
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Service 'app-fe-webapp' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yarn add serve-handler' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Error 3**

same error as above and got a warning

```
warning Pattern ["serve-handler@^6.1.3"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-serve-handler-6.1.3-1bf8c5ae138712af55c758477533b9117f6435e8-integrity/node_modules/serve-handler" as pattern ["serve-handler@6.1.3"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
```

The serve.js resides in the same directory where Docker resides.

1. Am following correctly?
2. Is this related to the file path or somehow the serve.js is unable to find the packages.
3. When we overriding the serve with serve.js, is there any option we need to specify to use the serve.js
4. Is the command used in Docker file are correct ?
   OLD : `CMD ["serve", "-s", "./dist", "-p", "8080"]`
   NEW : `CMD ["node",serve.js"]`

Thanks in advance foe your time.

Thanks